# Event bubbling not happen in IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, iframe

I am thinking this is innocent question but really i don't know the answer still yet.

We all know that Event bubbling directs an event to its intended target, it works like this: A button is clicked and the event is directed to the button. If an event handler is set for that object, the event is triggered. If no event handler is set for that object, the event bubbles up (like a bubble in water) to the objects parent.

Html part

```
<div>
  <iframe>
    <a>Clickable fdf Area</a>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

javascript part

```
    $('div iframe').load(function(){
    var iframeBody = $(this).contents().find("body");
  iframeBody.html("<a href='www.google.com'>clickable area</a>");
  iframeBody.on("click", "a", function(){
    alert(22222);
  });
 document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event){
        alert(11111);
 }, true);

});
$('iframe').attr("src","JavaScript:'iframe content'");
```

My question is clear. 
when I try to click on the iframe 'a' tag why i am not getting the alert(11111)?
why the event bubbling is not held and what are the ways to access the event buubling through the code?

also reference [**Fiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/4HQc4/1454/)

Comment: This is a result of the same origin policy, you can't communicate with code from another domain unless it consents and even then it's message passing.

Comment: My question is clear. when I try to click on the iframe 'a' tag why i am not getting the alert(11111)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bubbling is specced to happen only through a single document tree.  The `iframe` is a *separate* document tree, and so events that bubble through its tree terminate at the root of the iframe's document and do not travel across the boundary into the host document.

> Capture operates from the top of the tree, generally the Document, downward

~ [Document Object Model Events: 1.2.2. Event capture](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-capture)

> This upward propagation will continue up to and including the Document.

~ [Document Object Model Events: 1.2.3. Event bubbling](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling)

Comment: How can we propagate the events into the iframe manually?